# Adding MQTT connection with different client id in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mqtt, paho

My program gets real-time data for multiple devices over MQTT. I'm using `spring-integration-mqtt` version 5.5.13. The MQTT broker uses different client ids for each device. Everything's fine with a static and predefined client id. The problem arises when I try to add new adapter of class `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`. The problem is that I can't.

I have defined a bean for `MqttPahoClientFactory` and `MessageChannel`. I also have a bean for the `MessageHandler` class that is annotated with the following:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttChannel") // mqttChannel is the adapter output channel
```

When I need a new connection that has its own client id, I call the method below.

```
public MessageProducer inbound() {
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
                new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("tcp://localhost:1883", "testClient",
                                                 "topic1", "topic2");
        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(1);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
        return adapter;
    }
```

I'm guessing it doesn't submit as a listener because it's not a bean. I don't know if I can have multiple bean of one type added at runtime.

I didn't have any luck defining two beans of the `MessageProducer` type with different qualifiers. only one of them works.

Maybe simply calling the inbound method won't connect and subscribe? or the output channel isn't being called?

I'm new to MQTT and this is my first time trying this. also my first ever question so I hope it's a good one:)

Comment: I'd usually expect to see each client publish to a different topic (i.e. `device1/data`) and subscribers connecting once, and subscribing to multiple topics on that connection/Client ID (perhaps via wildcards). Just thought it was worth checking that you actually need to connect multiple times? (sorry can't help with spring-boot!).

Comment: hi. i queried what you said but sadly this is the way it is implemented and i don't have another choice but to use it this way. thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I ended up using Eclipse Paho Client Mqttv3. It hasn't been updated in 2 years but it lets me manage my mqtt connections more direct and gets the job done.